# Edit in-place multiple input fields

Tags: jquery, forms, input, edit-in-place

I'm building a page where users can place multiple containers with input fields that can be edited in place. My script at the moment allows me to edit in place the input fields on click but I'm running into 2 issues:

1. I need to edit each form individually. At the moment when click on Edit all of the fields in the other containers become editable as well.
2. When click cancel nothing should be saved if anything was typed.

**[See DEMO](https://codepen.io/TNesta/pen/KByYEd)**

**JQuery**

```
var readonly = true;
$(".edit").on("click", function(e) {
  $('input[type="text"]').attr("readonly", !readonly);
  readonly = !readonly;
  $(".edit").hide();
  $(".button-group").show();
});
$(".save, .cancel").on("click", function() {
  $(".button-group").hide();
  $(".edit").show();
  $('input[type="text"]').attr("readonly", !readonly);
  readonly = !readonly;
});
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to target the parent of the parent element from `this` then you can scope your elements correctly. Move `.cancel` to its own listener, and then share the code to close the inputs for both `.cancel` and `.save` listeners.

You also don't need to keep the `readonly` attribute. You can simply remove it. See below for full example.

```
var closeInputs = function(selector, type) {
  var parent = $(selector).parent().parent();
  parent.find(".button-group").hide();
  parent.find(".edit").show();
  // loops through each input
  parent.find('input[type="text"]').each(function() {
    // gets the value from the input if 'save', else get the value of the data-value attribute;
    // default to empty string if either is undefined
    var value = (type === 'save' ? $(this).val() : $(this).attr('data-value')) || '';
    // update this input to readonly, set the data-value attribute with a value, then set the input value
    $(this).attr("readonly", true).attr('data-value', value).val(value);
  });
};
$(".edit").on("click", function(e) {
  var parent = $(this).parent().parent();
  parent.find('input[type="text"]').removeAttr("readonly");
  parent.find(".edit").hide();
  parent.find(".button-group").show();
});
$(".save").on("click", function() {
  closeInputs(this, 'save');
  alert('Going to save.');
});
$(".cancel").on("click", function() {
  closeInputs(this, 'cancel');
  alert('Not going to save.');
});
```

JS Fiddle: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/zLWLXM

Comment: I noticed that if you type something and click cancel it still saves it. Other than that everything seems fine. Thank you.

Comment: Yeah, you can clear the value on the cancel listener. Trivially easy to do now.

Comment: I'm not too sure how to do that. I've tried using $('input[type="text"]').val(null); in the cancel listener but that clears the whole input field. Sorry I'm not very good with JQuery.

Comment: `$(this).parent().parent().find('input[type="text"]').val('');` added to above answer.

Comment: If you type something and save it and then edit that same input field and just add more text to whatever you typed previously. Then press cancel everything gets cleared and it should only the new text added to be cleared. I hope this makes sense. Thank you.

Comment: Updated. The comments I added should explain how it works. To preload your inputs with save data (if you want), you have to  set `value="yourValue"` and `data-value="yourValue"` on every input on your HTML.

Comment: Perfect it works great! Thank you so much for the explanation.